# Prove that $\|R\|_2 = \|A\|_2^{1/2}$ where $A=R^* R$ is a Cholesky factorization of $A$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, svd, spectral-norm, cholesky-decomposition

Prove that $\|R\|_2 = \|A\|_2^{1/2}$ where $A = R^* R$ is a Cholesky factorization of $A$.

In my book it says that I should use the Singular Value Decomposition.

I have that
$\rho(A)=\sqrt{\rho(A^*A)}=\sqrt{\rho(A*A)}=\sqrt{\rho(A^2)}$
$$ \Rightarrow \rho^2(A)=\rho(A^2)$$

So, I have tried:

$R^*R=Q\Sigma V^*$ where $Q\Sigma V^*$, is de SVd of A.
Then $\rho(R^*R)=\rho(Q\Sigma V^*)$. With $\rho(.)$ is the bigger eigenvalue.

We conclude that $\rho^2(R)=\rho(A) \Leftrightarrow ||R||=\sqrt{||A||}$.

This last equation comes from the relation between the singular value of A in its norm.

I do not know if this process is well formulated.

Comment: What have you tried? Do you understand how the singular value decomposition might be useful here?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I have add in my questions my new try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** What is the relationship between the eigenvalues of $A$ and the singular values of $R$? Using the fact that $A$ is self-adjoint, what is $\|A\|$ in terms of the eigenvalues of $A$? What is $\|R\|$, in terms of the eigenvalues of $A$?

Comment: Dear, friend, I have added the hint in the question. Was it what you mean?

Comment: @JuanMuñoz It is not true that $\|R\| = \rho(R)$. Look closely at the definition of $\|R\|_2$.

Comment: I have found a proof without using SDV:
$A=R^*R \leftarrow ||A||=\rho(A)=\rho(R^*R)$ because A is Hermitean and
$||R||=\sqrt{\rho(R^*R)}=\sqrt{||A||}$

But here I did not use the SVD. As was required in the Excersise. Is it a good approach?

Comment: @Juan Yes, that approach is fine. I assume that the SVD is useful if you use a different definition for $\|R\|$.

Comment: So at the end Wich is the answer that use SVD. Do I need to use the SVD  of $R$

Comment: @JuanMuñoz If you define $\|R\|$ to be the largest singular value of $R$, then it makes sense to use the SVD